# Sentinel::getUser() only returns null in appServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel, cartalyst-sentinel

I wanted to use Sentinel::getUser() in the AppServiceProvider.php to make it global in all front-end files.

I include it in the boot function, like this:

```
view()->share( 'loggedUser', Sentinel::getUser() );
```

or

```
View::share("loggedUser",Sentinel::getUser());
```

Also have I included:

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;
```

But when I do it the only response is NULL. When I use Sentinel:getuser() in a blade file it works.

Not only is it giving NULL as response, when I have that included my php artisan also return NULL on every command I make.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? :)

Comment: Laravel version 5.4.28

Comment: What about [view creators/composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)? Creators run before variables are set, composers run after, so they override values passed in when creating the view.

Comment: The thing with view creators/composers is that its good to bind to a partial what u use more times in the application. But I need to reach it from all views. Thats why I want it globaly.